# Unable to create new notebook in Jupyter Notebook in windows 7

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

While clicking python 3 ,it shows python is not working

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBUxC.jpg)

This is the error i'm getting.

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdE8I.jpg)

Version Jupyter notebook 6.0.3 from anaconda.

Python 3.7

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Edit :
Jupyter Lab is also throwing same error

Adding error details

Problem signature:

Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH

Application Name: python.exe

Application Version:  3.7.6150.1013

Application Timestamp:    5e163a94

Fault Module Name:    KERNELBASE.dll

Fault Module Version: 6.1.7600.16385

Fault Module Timestamp:   4a5bdfe0

Exception Code:   40000015

Exception Offset: 000000000000aa7d

OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1

Locale ID:    1033

Additional Information 1: 3658

Additional Information 2: 36588e52e11b5ed6a58475ad849ab96f

Additional Information 3: a77c

Additional Information 4:   a77c3161a7d50fc4b928979053988a6f

Comment: Please post errors as formatted text and don't link to images.

Comment: @TomStroemer added